# Div com sobreposição de carregamento

Tags: jquery, html, css

Olá, tenho a seguinte `div` e fiz um código em jquery para quando acioná-la por meio de um evento, ela apareça, porém quero estilizá-la de uma forma que a div sobreponha todo o conteúdo da minha página, com um fundo preto com certa opacidade e um mostre meu conteúdo da `div`, estou tentando estilizar porém sem sucesso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui].

Segue meu código:

```
   <div class="mask-loading">
        <figure>
           <img src="img/ajax-loading.gif" alt="carregando...">
           <figcaption class="loading-text"></figcaption>
        </figure>
    </div>
```

Comment: Não entendi. A forma que você quer é essa da imagem ou a forma que está hoje é essa da imagem?

Comment: Sim, a forma que eu quero é a da imagem

Comment: Não entendi muito bem, faltou seu código jquery e css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicamente, basta adicionar as seguintes propriedades no CSS:

```
.mask-loading {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      z-index: 1000;
      background-color: #000;
      opacity: 0.5;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
}
```

Dessa forma você está adicionando a cor, a opacidade, tamanho e posição para sua `div`.

Abaixo está um exemplo do funcionamento. Não é o seu modelo, mas é possível entender o que deseja.

```js
$('#loader').click(function() {
  $('.mask-loading').show();

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.mask-loading').hide();
  }, 5000);
});
```

```css
.mask-loading {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 0.5;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
}
img {
  top: 500px;
  z-index: 1000;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mask-loading">
  <figure>
    <img src="http://www.mtlexs.com/images/reload.gif" alt="carregando...">
    <figcaption class="loading-text"></figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>

<div>
  sua página aqui
</div>

<button id="loader">Loader</button>
```

> Existe várias formas de fazer o que deseja. Porém, como desconheço o seu código, adicionei uma forma que creio que deva funcionar para você.

Comment: Perfeito @Randrade, porém a opacidade está pegando o spinner tbm, sabe como resolver? Tentei editar diretamente na classe com um !important e nada..

Comment: @João Coloque o `z-index` do spinner maior que o da div. Editei a resposta adicionando um fundo brando no spinner.

Comment: no meu não funcionou. Continuam com a mesma opacidade

Comment: @João Infelizmente, não tem como ajudar sem saber como está o seu CSS. Você pode tentar adicionar `!importante;` para ver. Porém, seria melhor se você postasse o código completo para vermos o que está causando o conflito.

Comment: Segue https://jsfiddle.net/9m12L0rc/

Comment: @João Isso é porque o gif que você escolheu possui o fundo branco. [Veja seu exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/9m12L0rc/1/) com outro gif que entenderá.

Comment: Entendi @Randrade, muito obrigado!